# CANOe Diagnostic console show Error when processing of response message("Primitive has invalid length")

Tags: can-bus, diagnostics, capl, canoe, uds

In CANOe Diagnostic console when I request SID and I see **Error when processing of response message("Primitive has invalid length")** and I receive Positive response message. Please could someone tell me how to remove[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7lI.png) the above error ? I have attached a screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Basic Diagnostics Editor there is the parameter "sessionParameterRecord" configured, which is missing in the received response.
That`s why the Diagnostic Console reports that the "primtive has an invalid length", it`s too short

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N7ie.png)